# Android: HashMap Not supporting newline character

Tags: android, android-listview

I have developed an application. For the Instructions Page, I have created an Expandable list view. The parent represents Each button in the applications main screen and the child contains the details of what would happen on the button press of the corresponding parent button.

My expandable list view is based on the `HashMap` concept. I have extended my class with the `ExpandableListActivity`. Int the `onCreate` Method i have defined a `SimpleExpandableListAdapter` as shown below:

```
SimpleExpandableListAdapter expListAdapter=
                new SimpleExpandableListAdapter(
                        this,
                        createGroupList(),
                        R.layout.group_row,
                        new String[] { "parent" },
                        new int[] { R.id.row_name },
                        createChildList(),
                        R.layout.child_row,
                        new String[] {"Sub Item"},
                        new int[] { R.id.grp_child}

                        );
        setListAdapter(expListAdapter);
```

The definition for `createGroupList()` and `createChildList()` is as shown below:

```
public List createGroupList()
{
     ArrayList result = new ArrayList();
     for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
     {
        HashMap m=new HashMap();
        if(i==0)
            m.put("parent","Start Rec");
        else if(i==1)
            m.put("parent","automated Rec");
        result.add( m );
     }
     return (List)result;
}

public List createChildList()
    {
        ArrayList result = new ArrayList();

        for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
        {
            ArrayList secList = new ArrayList();
            for(int j=0;j<1;j++)
            {   
                HashMap child = new HashMap();
                if(i==0)
                {
                    if(j==0)
                    {
                        child.put( "Sub Item", "In this Mode\n user can start recording a video without a preview.\n\nSteps:\n1)Click on the \"Start Rec\" Button. 2) Once the button is clicked, the color and text message on the button change and the recording gets started in the background.\n3)The User should now Minimize the App using the Home Button and can continue recording.\n4)Inorder to stop recording the user should can Mazimize the minimized App and press on the \"Stop Rec\" Button to stop recording."); 
                        secList.add( child );
                    }
                }
                else if(i==1)
                {
                    if(j==0)
                    {
                        child.put( "Sub Item", "\\Multiple lines of exp here"); 
                        secList.add( child );
                    }                       
                }

            result.add( secList );
        }
        return result;      
    }
```

Now, in the above example, In the "Sub Item" HashMap, as soon as the **"\n"** new line character is encountered, i do not get any text . And if there is no \n, i get only single line display, that is only a part/ single line of the message is displayed and the other part is hidden/ not seen.

Any help reg this will be really helpful to me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This has nothing to do with maps (although you *should* use generics rather than using the raw map). `HashMap` doesn't care what text you use.

Comment: If HashMap doesnt care what text i use, then why isn't it considering the newline character. 
As soon as it encounters newline character, the preceeding text is not diaplayed at all.

Comment: If you think there is another alternative please suggest one.

Comment: This sounds like it's a matter of the *display* aspect, not the hash map at all. You can test that very easily - just fetch the text back out of the map using the key, and log the length. I strongly suspect you'll see the length of the complete string being logged. It's not obvious to me (as not-an-Android-developer) why you'd expect the newline to work in the GUI, but it *does* seem clear to me that it's not about the map...